# What does the Golden Spatula do in Legends of Runeterra's Lab of Legends?

Tags: legends-of-runeterra

There is a new item in Lab of Legends that has a very mysterious description. If I pick the Golden Spatula what actually happens to the card it is attached to?

[image: A golden spatula]

As you can see, I have it on my Laurent Chevalier but his stats and keywords did not change.

Answer (score 1):

I think it gives you +2/+0, shuffles your stats and gives a random keyword

Comment: I had this on Azir and he ended up with +2/+0 and quick attack.  As it supports this answer but not the OP screenshot, perhaps it's champions only?